# VBA to format cells based on another cell not working

Tags: vba, excel, macros

**SOLVED: FOUND MY OWN WORKSHEET ERROR**
The problem I was having was trying to use two worksheet_change events in the same workbook. Because I thought that was possible, I was just renaming the worksheet event in question when I received an error, thinking nothing of it. Both my original code and the answer provided work, when combined with my other worksheet_change event.
Thanks everyone.

Original Request:

I am trying to run a macro that does this:

every time cell r6 changes, run a macro that looks to see if the value in cell s9 is > or < 1, then format cells s9:t100 based on that.

I have the macro on its own to do the second part:

```
sub macro1()
If Range("S9").Value < 1 Then
      Range("S9:S100,T9:T100").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
Else
        Range("S9:S100,T9:T100").Select
      Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End If
end sub
```

This macro run on its own, works exactly as I want and formats the cells.

Then I have the worksheet event to call up that macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$R$6" Then
Call Macro1
End If
End Sub
```

When it is run to call up the same macro, it does not format the cells. They just stay as a % regardless of when cell r6 changes.

Any ideas why the worksheet event causes the macro to not work?

Comment: Is the value in R6 changing as the result of a formula, or by direct user input?   `Worksheet_Change` doesn't capture the first of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the worksheet object to your macro. This fully qualifies the `Ranges` to make sure you're working on the right area.

Also, you don't need to `Select` at all. Just use the range and directly change the settings.

```
Public Sub Macro1(ws as Worksheet)
    If ws.Range("S9").Value < 1 Then
        ws.Range("S9:S100,T9:T100").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Else
        ws.Range("S9:S100,T9:T100").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End If
end sub

Sub test()
    Macro1 ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

And in your `Worksheet_Change`...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$R$6" Then
        Macro1 Target.Worksheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. First, this combination is producing the same problem. But also, when I add the public macro above to a module, it does not show up in my macro list so I can't test it on its own to make sure it works. I don't need to change anything in there to fit my workbook right? Does the excel version matter? I am stuck in 2007

Comment: Both the `Worksheet_Change` event and the `Macro1` work perfectly fine for me. I added a quick test sub above for debugging as an illustration. In the VBA Editor, put your edit cursor in the `test()` sub, then press F5 to execute, or press F8 to step. You can check each statement along the way if necessary. Is your `Worksheet_Change` sub on the Sheet module (not your code module)?

Comment: yeah, same problem as originally still. when I run the macro1 on its own, it correctly formats everything. But as part of the worksheet_change, it appears to do nothing. I'm totally baffled by this one. Maybe my workbook is just too messy. There are other things going on, but nothing that should interact. I will try to isolate a new workbook to just this section and try that. Thanks again.

Comment: working in the recreation i did in another workbook. something must be up with the one I am working in. I will have to troubleshoot. thanks for your solution.